# Does RcppArmadillo enable bandicoot?

Tags: c++, r, gpu, rcpp, armadillo

I just would like to know if RcppArmadillo enables bandicoot, or is there any other way to enable gpu calculation with RcppArmadillo?

Thank you, maybe it is too generalized but i did not find much info on the web about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entire Armadillo repo is *completely free of any reference to [bandicoot](https://github.com/conradsnicta/bandicoot-code)* so how could RcppArmadillo possibly support it?

```
edd@rob:~/git/armadillo-code(unstable)$ ag bandicoot          # silversearcher
edd@rob:~/git/armadillo-code(unstable)$ grep -r bandicoot .   # standard grep
edd@rob:~/git/armadillo-code(unstable)$
```

Also note that [bandicoot](https://github.com/conradsnicta/bandicoot-code) is still labelled experimental.

We do have GPU support from R though, see eg [RcppArrayFire](https://github.com/RInstitute/rcpparrayfire).